# Hide UIViewController in NavigationController stack

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

I have two controllers, controller 1 and Controller 2, controller 1 push controller 2 and controller 2 do its work and pop after done its work automatically.
Now I want that controller 2 will not be visible from when its push to pop and user remain see controller 1 until controller popped.

**I Tried:**

Once I tried it turns into black page in push and pop, and when I try to use as Present Model, the controller 1 squeezed down for that period of time when controller 2 is doing its work til dismiss

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[self presentModalViewController:controller2 animated:false];
```

NOTE: I can do all the work on some Object class or controller 1 but its very old project in Objective C and too lengthy class so that I'll go another option.

Looking for suggestion and help on this.

Thanks

Comment: @Sh_Khan I already explained in Note that why can't I do in VC1 due to too much code and too much time taking to transfer

Comment: if all  what you do is a processing not UI then define another viewModel class and do the work inside it

Comment: @Sh_Khan As explained that if its easy I would rather chose to transfer into some other but its pre condition that I'll not transfer but to hide controller, will it possible to hide it ?

Comment: Althouth it's a terrible hack, you can try adding the VC2 as a child view controller of VC1 with zero frame. However, refactoring is the best way.

Comment: @Aleem - what code is executing in `VC2`? If it can run without presenting a UI, you don't *need* to present or push to it. You can instantiate it, run the code, and then delete it when done.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create another viewModel class  , but you can do this

```
UIViewController*vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VCName"];
[self addChildViewController:vc];
[vc.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)]; 
vc.view.hidden = YES; // here you hide the vc2's view
[self.view addSubview:vc.view];
[vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```